# SQL query - Dept and Employee table, some departments may not have managers

Tags: sql

There are two tables:

```
Employee 
---------
emp_id
emp_name 
emp_contact 
salary 
mgr_emp_Id
Dept_No 

Dept 
-----
Dept_No
Dept_name
Dept_Location
```

Write a SQL statement to list all department names along with location and also manager name if a manager has been assigned to the department. Note that some departments still do not have a manager.
Is the following correct?

```
SELECT Dept_name, Dept_Location, emp_name AS Mgr_name 
FROM Dept 
LEFT JOIN Employee ON (Dept.Dept_No = Employee.Dept_No AND mgr_emp_id = emp_id)
```

Can this be achieved without join too? If yes, how?

Comment: This is probably not correct.  Without sample data, though, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Well, did you try running it and see the results?

Comment: I tried with very simple data - added 2 rows in Dept table but put only 1 row in employee table and this row corresponds to one of the departments. I get correct result i.e. for one department, I get manager name as in the employee table and for the other department, the manager name is null. But I am not sure if it will work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that without a JOIN, even though I prefer using JOINs. Your query will have to be modified. Here's how...

### Example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/596b45/4 (MySQL 5.5)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbad4/1 (SQL Server 2008)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bbad4/1 (PostgreSQL 9.2)

### Assumption

1) In the employee table: manager id + department id will be unique

2) In the employee table: if employee Clark is ID 5 and has a manager with ID 1, there will a record in the table with ID 1

3) MySQL 5.5 is being used

### Structure

```
create table dept
(
  dept_no int not null,
  dept_name varchar(100) not null,
  dept_location varchar(100) not null,
  primary key (dept_no)
);

create table employee 
(
  emp_id int not null,
  emp_name varchar(100) not null,
  mgr_emp_id int,
  dept_no int not null,
  primary key (emp_id),
  key employee_mgr_emp_id (mgr_emp_id),
  foreign key fk_employee_dept_dept_no (dept_no) references dept (dept_no) on delete no action on update no action
);

insert into dept values 
(1, 'Dept-1', 'Chicago'), 
(2, 'Dept-2', 'London');

insert into employee values 
(1, 'Clark Mgr', null, 1),
(2, 'Cameron Emp', 1, 1),
(3, 'Charlie Emp', 1, 1),
(4, 'Layton Emp', null, 2),
(5, 'Linda Emp', null, 2);
```

### MySQL 5.5 query

**Without JOIN**

```
select 
  list.*,
  emp_id,
  emp_name
from employee, 
(
  select
    distinct 
    dept.dept_no, 
    dept.dept_name, 
    dept.dept_location, 
    employee.mgr_emp_id
  from dept, employee
  where 
    dept.dept_no = employee.dept_no
    and employee.mgr_emp_id is not null
) list
where
  employee.emp_id = list.mgr_emp_id;
```

**With JOIN** (although not completely identical to the above. I prefer using `JOIN`s)

```
select 
  list.*,
  emp_id,
  emp_name
from employee
inner join 
(
  select
    distinct 
    dept.dept_no, 
    dept.dept_name, 
    dept.dept_location, 
    employee.mgr_emp_id
  from dept
  left join employee on dept.dept_no = employee.dept_no
  where 
    employee.mgr_emp_id is not null
) list
on employee.emp_id = list.mgr_emp_id;
```

### How does it work

First we want to get a list of all departments that have a manager ID of not null in the employee table. To do that, we use this query below. This query will give 2 records for Chicago because there are 2 records in employee table with a valid manager ID for Chicago's department.

**Without JOIN**

```
select
  dept.dept_no,
  dept.dept_name,
  dept.dept_location,
  employee.mgr_emp_id
from dept, employee
where
    dept.dept_no = employee.dept_no
    and employee.mgr_emp_id is not null;
```

**With JOIN**

```
select
  dept.dept_no,
  dept.dept_name,
  dept.dept_location,
  employee.mgr_emp_id
from dept
left join employee on dept.dept_no = employee.dept_no
where
    employee.mgr_emp_id is not null;
```

To get only one record, we will use distinct keyword:

```
  select
    distinct 
    dept.dept_no, 
    ...
```

Great, so now we know who the manager is for each department no. Let's find this person's name. To do that, we put our query in a subquery (which I nicknamed/aliased as `list`) and then combine it with employee table to get the desired result.